# Centering segmented button in container?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I've got a TabBar nav with a segmentedbutton that also contains a card
layout.  Everything works fine. However, I'm trying to get my
segmentedbutton centered on the screen.  I don't want it to stretch.  I've included the main views and placed all the code on
[SenchaFiddle](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#KFylK)

[image]

[image]

```
Ext.define('SenchaFiddle.view.SegView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'seg-view',

    config: {
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [
            {
                layout: 'vbox',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'segmentedbutton',
                        allowDepress: true,
                        items: [
                            {
                                text: 'Option 1',
                                pressed: true,
                                handler: function() {
                                    console.log("Picked #1");
                                    Ext.getCmp('card-container').setActiveItem(0);
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                text: 'Option 2',
                                handler: function() {
                                    Ext.Msg.alert("foo");

                                    Ext.getCmp('card-container').setActiveItem(1);
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                text: 'Option 3',
                                handler: function() {
                                    Ext.getCmp('card-container').setActiveItem(2);
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'container',
                        flex: 10,
                        id: 'card-container',
                        layout: {
                            type: 'card'
                        },
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'option-view1',
                                style: 'background-color: #fff'
                            },
                            {
                                html: 'bar',
                                style: 'background-color: #666'

                            },
                            {
                                html: 'baz',
                                style: 'background-color: #333'

                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }

        ]
    }
});
```

```
Ext.define('SenchaFiddle.view.MainView', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    xtype: 'test-view',
    id: 'test-view',

    config: {
        tabBarPosition:'bottom',
        layout: {
            type: 'card',
            animation: {
                duration: 300,
                easing: 'ease-in-out',
                type: 'slide',
                direction: 'left'
            }
        },
        fullscreen: true,

        items: [
            {
                title: 'Tab1',
                iconCls: 'info',
                xtype: 'panel',
                layout: {
                    type: 'fit'
                },
                items: [
                    {
                        title: 'Title 1',
                        xtype: 'toolbar',
                        docked: 'top'
                    },
                    {
                        id: 'image-tab',
                        html: 'Loading foo...'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'seg-view',
                        layout: 'fit'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                title: 'Tab2',
                iconCls: 'action',
                items: [
                    {
                        title: 'Title 2',
                        xtype: 'toolbar',
                        docked: 'top'
                    },
                    {
                        id: 'news-tab',
                        html: 'Loading bar...'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just can you use `layout:{pack:'center'}` try to put you after `allowDepress: true` and have fun! centered.

Just like this:

```
Ext.define('SenchaFiddle.view.SegView', {
extend: 'Ext.Container',
xtype: 'seg-view',

config: {
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [
        {
            layout: 'vbox',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'segmentedbutton',
                    allowDepress: true,
                    layout: {pack:'center'},
                    ...
```

**Smarter** :)

Comment: I guess your answer is a little better.  I voted both of you up and gave you the check.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is put your segmentedbutton in an hbox layout an surround with with spacers :

```
Ext.define('SenchaFiddle.view.SegView', {
  extend: 'Ext.Container',
  xtype: 'seg-view',

  config: {
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [
    {
      layout: 'vbox',
      items: [{
        xtype:'container',
        layout:'hbox',
        items:[{xtype:'spacer'},
        {
          xtype: 'segmentedbutton',
          allowDepress: true,
          items: [
          {
            text: 'Option 1',
            pressed: true,
            handler: function() {
              console.log("Picked #1");
              Ext.getCmp('card-container').setActiveItem(0);
            }
          },
          {
            text: 'Option 2',
            handler: function() {
              Ext.getCmp('card-container').setActiveItem(1);

            }
          },
          {
            text: 'Option 3',
            handler: function() {
              Ext.getCmp('card-container').setActiveItem(2);
            }
          }
          ]
          },{xtype:'spacer'}]},
          {
            xtype: 'container',
            flex: 10,
            id: 'card-container',
            layout: {
              type: 'card'
            },
            items: [
            {
              xtype: 'option-view1',
              style: 'background-color: #fff'
            },
            {
              html: 'bar',
              style: 'background-color: #666'

            },
            {
              html: 'baz',
              style: 'background-color: #333'

            }
            ]
          }
          ]
        }

        ]
      }
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Notice that the "Loading" message is on the same line as the segmentedbutton?  I want to put a few other rows of information above it.  How can I get the button to appear below the message?

Comment: By the way, is there an easy way to duplicate a SenchaFiddle so I can show additional changes from the original?

Comment: I'm not a big fan of SenchaFiddle, so I don't know.

Comment: And if you want to put something above the segmented button like the 'Loading' message, just put in the Vbox container before the segmented button and not in the html attribute of a tab panel's item