# How to set the margin and padding on a container?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I found this
StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937936/centering-segmented-button-in-container)
on which I'm basing my next project.

For each of the "Option" segment button, I want to show a different
HTML page.  I've changed the SegView class to accomplish this.  However, now
I'd like to set my left and right margin to provide a 10% gap.  In
other words, my content would be centered in the middle 80%.

Is it possible to simply configure my containers to have a margin so my content is jammed against the borders?

[image]

Here's the modified SegView class from the other StackOverFlow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937936/centering-segmented-button-in-container):

```
Ext.define('SenchaFiddle.view.SegView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'seg-view',

    config: {
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [
            {
                layout: 'vbox',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'segmentedbutton',
                        allowDepress: true,
                        layout:{pack:'center'},
                        items: [
                            {
                                text: 'Option 1',
                                pressed: true,
                                handler: function () {
                                    console.log("Picked #1");
                                    Ext.getCmp('card-container').setActiveItem(0);
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                text: 'Option 2',
                                handler: function () {
                                    Ext.getCmp('card-container').setActiveItem(1);

                                }
                            },
                            {
                                text: 'Option 3',
                                handler: function () {
                                    Ext.getCmp('card-container').setActiveItem(2);
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'container',
                        flex: 10,
                        id: 'card-container',
                        layout: {
                            type: 'card'
                        },
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'container',
                                style: 'background-color: #fff',

                                items: [
                                    {
                                        html: ['<h2 style="text-align: center;">Lorum ipsum</h2>',
                                        "<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>",
                                        '<p>Hello world</p>'].join("")
                                },
                                {
                                    html: ['<h2 style="text-align: center;">Lorum ipsum</h2>',
                                        "<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>",
                                        '<p>Hello world</p>'].join("")
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            html: ['<p>Lorum ipsum</p>',
                                '<p>Page #2</p>'].join(""),
                            style: 'background-color: #666'

                        },
                        {
                            html: ['<p>Lorum ipsum</p>',
                                '<p>Page #3</p>'].join(""),
                            style: 'background-color: #333'

                        }
                    ]
                    }
                ]
            }

        ]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give class to containser

```
    items: [{
       xtype: 'container',
       cls : 'content',
       items: [{
         html: ['<h2 style="text-align: center;">Lorum ipsum</h2>',
            "<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>",
            '<p>Hello world</p>'].join("")
         },
         {
          html: ['<h2 style="text-align: center;">Lorum ipsum</h2>',
             "<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>",
             '<p>Hello world</p>'].join("")}
        ]}
```

**CSS**

```
.content{
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    background-color: #fff;
 }
```

Comment: That'll do.  I also found that a container has margin: and padding: properties.  http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/source/Component.html#Ext-Component-cfg-margin and  http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Container

Comment: I like the margin property better. less code, and simpler: `margin: '10 5 10 5', `